# Wikidata Query - Health Specialty of a Disease name

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-api

I want to query the "instance of P31" and "health specialty P115" for a disease name
**"left bundle branch hemiblock (Q2143688)"**

I want an output like :

```
left bundle branch hemiblock (Q2143688)
instance of : thoracic disease
health specialty :cardiology
```

Also is it possible to query all disease information with its instance of and health specialty, so that I can store it and process each time I need an information.

Comment: for given diseases: `select ?disease ?diseaseLabel ?type ?typeLabel ?specialty ?specialtyLabel where {
VALUES ?disease {wd:Q2143688}
?disease wdt:P31 ?type ;
            wdt:P1995 ?specialty
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}`

Comment: for all diseases: `select ?disease ?diseaseLabel ?type ?typeLabel ?specialty ?specialtyLabel where {
?disease wdt:P31* wd:Q12136 .
?disease wdt:P31 ?type ;
            wdt:P1995 ?specialty
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}`

Comment: @UninformedUser - Any idea why I'm not able to get the same information for disease - asthma (Q35869)